# Corrupted Data in Open Address Unordered Maps

Tags: c++, hash, unordered-map

I was attempting to replace std::unordered_map<uint64_t, edge_type> (edge_type is a struct with two uint32_t members) with [robin_hood::unordered_flat_map<uint64_t, edge_type>](https://github.com/martinus/robin-hood-hashing). This caused my code to spinlock somehow, so I assumed it had something to do with invalidated iterators and hunted for a bug. I tried using `robin_hood::unordered_node_map` and that gave correct results, though slower than `std::unordered_map` so initially it seemed my hypothesis about iterators was correct.

I spent some time tracing through the code and found that somehow data being inserted into the array was corrupted.

```cpp
robin_hood::unordered_flat_map< uint64_t, edge_type >  edges_   ;
...
    void add_edge( uint32_t x, uint32_t y, uint32_t z, uint32_t f ) {
         const uint64_t e = detail::make_edge( x, y );
         ...
        std::cout << "e: " << e << " (" << f << ", " << z << ")" << std::endl;

        edges_.emplace(e, edge_type( f, z ));
        edge_type edg = edges_.at(e);
        std::cout << edg.face_ << " " << edg.vertex_ << std::endl;
        ZI_ASSERT( edges_.at(e) == edge_type(f,z) );
```

It turned out that the assertion statement was failing. I checked the output and added a few print statements to emplace:

```
e: 18446744073709551614 (1, 2)
new node
1 2
e: 18446744069414584317 (1, 0)
new node
1 0
e: 18446744065119617023 (1, 1)
new node
1 1
e: 18446744073709551613 (2, 3)
new node
2 3
e: 18446744065119617020 (2, 0)
new node
2 0
e: 18446744060824649727 (2, 2)
overwrite_node
1 2
Assertion failed: (edges_.at(e) == edge_type(f,z)), function add_edge, file tri_mesh.hpp, line 175.
```

As you can see at the last emplacement, the retrieved value is (1,2) when the value inserted was (2,2) for a unique key.

The original std::unordered_map code in question can be found here:

https://github.com/seung-lab/zmesh/blob/master/zi_lib/zi/mesh/tri_mesh.hpp#L171
https://github.com/seung-lab/zmesh/blob/master/zi_lib/zi/mesh/detail/tri_mesh_edge.hpp#L42-L48 (definition of edge_type)

I tried this with two other flat map implementations and had the same issue. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Have you run your code through `valgrind` or build with the address sanitizer turned on?

Comment: Show the code to `edge_type`, `make_edge` and related declarations of these edge things. If I had to guess, your `edge_type` is doing something inconsistent and perhaps contains an overloaded operator for ==. But that's just a guess until you share the code for a [mcve]

Comment: Copy assignment operator for `tri_mesh_edge_impl` is absolutely broken, I guess reallocation happens at some point before you see the error. You don't need neither copy constructor nor copy assignment operator, remove them.

Comment: @StephenNewell unfortunately valgrind doesn't work (easily) on MacOS. I could look into it again. Will have to look into address sanitizer as well.

Comment: `inline const tri_mesh_edge_impl* operator=( const tri_mesh_edge_impl& o ) const { return this; }` -- As pointed out, this is a case of stepping in and telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing when copies are made".  The compiler says "ok, I'll leave you to handle it".  But the problem is that you fouled up the whole thing, when the compiler's version would have worked without flaws.  The moral of the story -- don't write unnecessary code -- the less you have to write, the less chance of bugs will appear.

Comment: @selbie You can find the definition here: https://github.com/seung-lab/zmesh/blob/master/zi_lib/zi/mesh/detail/tri_mesh_edge.hpp#L42-L48  I should try to make a minimal example.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen and PaulMcKenzie thank you for that insight! I will have to investigate how to amend that. I tried simply removing it but the code gave an error: "cannot be assigned because its copy assignment operator is implicitly deleted" Will experiment more. This code was written by a grad student 12 years ago and my C++ isn't the sharpest, so I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @SapphireSun -- It's the `const` members that are messing things up for you.  Do those two members have to be `const int` instead of just `int`?

Comment: It compiles now! Thank you. I will have to test it for correctness. It is not immediately reproducing the previous error thankfully! It's going to sound very dumb, but I was experimenting with this for days.

Comment: emplace doesn't overwrite an existing element. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace

Comment: I'm running into another assertion error. I'll take that under advisement.

Comment: I figured it out, there were some references like `edge_type& el` that needed to be copies. Thank you so much! @Yksisarvinen or PaulMcKenzie if you post your solution I will approve it.